# How to sort numbers stored in a file. (Ascend and Descend) powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting

Is it possible to sort numbers in a file in ascending or descending? How is it done?

```
Get-ChildItem |Sort-Object .\sorting.txt\ -Descending
Get-Content |Sort-Object .\sorting.txt\ -Descending
```

I tried all of these and even `measure-object` but none of them gave me what I wanted- numbers in a file sorted in ascend/descend

Comment: I think you're looking for `Get-Content .\thefiletosort.txt  | Sort-Object { $_ -as [int] }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks it worked, but what about descending?

Comment: just add `-Descending` at the end :P

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon can you also answer this question pls....."Create one excel file, two word files, and try to retrieve only word files in sorted
order." I tried sort-object and then ".docx" but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following

**sorting.txt**

```
9
11
45
12
3
101
```

Then run:

```
Get-Content .\sorting.txt | Sort-Object { $_ -as [int] } -Descending >> ./sorted.txt
```

**sorted.txt**

```
101
45
12
11
9
3
```